# Is it possible to format standard java list output?

Tags: java

I have a java list which contains 125 integers.  My output when I print the list is the standard List output:  `[5, 54, 75, ...]`.  All integers are printed on one long line.  I realize I can loop and add a \n after a desired number of integers.  Is it possible to format the output to add a line-break after 10 integers are listed while keeping this standard output, without a loop?

Desired output style:

```
[5, 54, 75, 56, 76, 87, 56, 98, 56, 93  
47, 95, 65, 85, 48, 85, 65, 68, 45, 89  
84, 56, 62]
```

Is their a `printf` or `format` method I have not found in my research to get this desired 10 integer per line output?

```
               private void printKeywordOccurrences(PrintWriter writer) {
                   for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : keywordMap.entrySet()) {
                       writer.println(entry.getKey() + " =");
                       writer.print("[");

                       List occurrList = entry.getValue();
                       int lastElement = occurrList.size();

                       if (!occurrList.isEmpty()) {

                           for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < (lastElement - 1); i++, j++) {
                               writer.print(occurrList.get(i));
                               writer.print(",");

                               if (j == 10) {
                                   writer.println();
                                   j = 0;

                                   } else {
                                       writer.print(" ");
                                   }

                               writer.print(occurrList.get(lastElement - 1));
                          }
                               writer.println("]\n");
                      }
                }
```

Comment: It's possible, but what have you tried??

Comment: That's a bit of a specific problem to be included as a built-in function don't you think?

Comment: Why are you anti-loop?

Comment: @Sanchit see code above, not anti-loop.  Just seeking more productive and different way to do things.

Comment: Different, sure. More efficient/'productive'? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to find every group of 10 integers and add a newline to them:

```
String formatted = list.toString().replaceAll("((\\d+, ){9}\\d+), ", "$1" + System.lineSeparator());
```

Comment: Great answer @Bohemian!  I have a lot to learn about regex I appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Pshemo thx - didn't notice the missing commas. I basically came up with your regex, except `\s` is not needed because it's always a space, and there's never a trailing comma, so the optional `?` for the trailing space is not required

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive solution as follows, you will note that the second `printList` calls the first.

```
private static void printList(List<?> al, int index) {
  // Set up an ending condition.
  if (al == null || index >= al.size()) {
    // close brace, print newline.
    System.out.print("]");
    System.out.println();
    return;
  }
  // are we at the first one?
  if (index > 0) {
    if (index % 10 == 0) {
      // interval of ten, new line.
      System.out.println(",");
    } else {
      // just a comma and a space.
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
  } else {
    // we are at the first one, open bracket.
    System.out.print("[");
  }
  // print the list entry
  System.out.print(al.get(index));
  // recurse.
  printList(al, index + 1);
}

// The public method signature.
public static void printList(List<?> al) {
  printList(al, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is their a printf or format method I have not found in my research to get this desired 10 integer per line output?

There isn't one in the standard Java libraries.  AFAIK.

I haven't come across a 3rd party library method to do this either.

I think your current approach is the best one ... write your own method to meet your own (special) formatting requirements.  (Using a regex to reformatted a string is just a bit too hacky for my taste ...)